# Update configuration for actively used index without data loss

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes, I need to update mappings, settings, or bind default pipelines to the actively used index.

For the time being, I am using a method **with** data loss as follows:

1. update the index template with proper mapping (or binding the default pipeline by [`index.default_pipeline`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings));
2. create `a_new_index` (matching the [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/indices-templates.html) `index_patterns`);
3. [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) the `index_to_fix` to `a_new_index` to migrate the data already indexed;
4. use [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases-api-add-multi-alias-ex) to redirect the coming indexing request to `a_new_index` (the alias will have the same name as `index_to_fix` to ensure the indexing is undisturbed) and delete the `index_to_fix`;

But between step 3 and step 4, there is a time gap, during which the newly indexed data are lost in the original `index_to_fix`.

---

Is there a way, to update configurations for actively used index without any data loss?

Comment: The solution( i have the same context with updated - deleted documents) is the use timestamps in your document. Once the reindex done, change alias and reindex by querry documents according to timestamps.

Comment: @lebigcat, good idea, but there is a problem, I have to ensure the alias will have the same name as `index_to_fix` which means I have to delete the `index_to_fix` when creating the alias. And the problem is still there. => `Invalid alias name [my_test1], an index exists with the same name as the alias`

Comment: The alias is a link on an index. You dont have to delete the old index, you can keep it a little. For exemple index1, index2, indexalias target index1, you reindex on index2. Change the alias target, on index2. index1 is still alive, you can delete it later.

Comment: @lebigcat sorry for the misunderstanding, I think that will not do since I have to create an alias (same name as the old index: `index_to_fix`), I have to delete the old index `index_to_fix` first within _aliases `actions` using `remove_index`. But if I delete the old index, then the data will be lost (during the gap).

Comment: you shouldnot set alias name = index name.

Comment: @lebigcat thanks for the help, in that case, it cannot do. The system is working on the `index_to_fix` and I have to **redirect** the indexing to the alias with the *same* name as `index_to_fix`. Perhaps I should design a better index template in the very beginning and operate CRUD upon the alias for each index instead of the index iteself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help of @LeBigCat, after some discussions. I think this problem could be solved in three steps.

#### Use Alias for CRUD

First thing first, try not to use index directly, use alias if possible; since you can't use an alias with the same name as the existed indices, directly you can't replace the index even if it's broken (badly designed). The easiest way is to use a template and include the index name directly in the alias.

```
PUT _template/test
{
  ...
  "aliases" : {
    "{index}-alias" : {} 
  }
}
```

#### Redirect the Indexing

Since the `index_to_fix` is being actively used, after updating the template and create a new index `a_new_fix`, we can use alias to **redirect** the indexing to `a_new_fix`.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add":  { "index": "a_new_index", "alias": "index_to_fix-alias" } },
        { "remove": { "index": "index_to_fix", "alias": "index_to_fix-alias" } }  
    ]
}
```

#### Migrating the Data

Simply use `_reindex` to migrate all the data from `index_to_fix` to `a_new_index`.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_to_fix"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_to_fix-alias"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it should work. You should make a snapshot (before delete the old index and not too "big") also if these is production data.